# What is the book of Jashar ( the book of the upright)?

Tags: joshua

In the book of Joshua, chapter 10, verses 13 through 15 they mentioned *Book of Jashar*

What is the book of Jashar ( ***the book of the upright***)?

Are there any surviving copies, or they all lost?

Comment: The book of Jasher is only mentioned in Josh 10:13 and 2 Sam 1:18.  Nothing more is known about it.  No copies exist.  See https://biblehub.com/topical/j/jasher.htm

Answer (score 2):

We have two references to the Book of The Upright a.k.a the Book of Jasher: Joshua 10:12 and 2 Samuel 1:18. The former tells us that Jasher contained Joshua's words to Israel on the occasion of the Sun's stop(Joshua 10:12-13) and the latter tells us that it contained *The Bow*, King David's lamentation over Saul and Jonathan(1 Samuel 1:19-27). That's about it.

So far, nobody's found any surviving copies. Anything currently around is a fake.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: +1 Indeed, there is a Mormon forgery of the book of Jasher that some might find which is fictitious and highly novelish--quite entertaining.  It begins at the beginning of Genesis and extends to the times of the kings.  Though written in a KJV-style language, and with some plausible passages, there are certain notable discrepancies with the actual Biblical record, showing it cannot be trusted.